# Classifying topos for higher order logic

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory, higher-order-logic

Chapter X of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* focuses on Classifying topoi. The basic concept in the early pages is the one of *geometric formula*, which is by definition a first-order formula.

Now, it is possible that it comes clear later in the book, but just for curiosity: is there a version of "Classifying topos" in higher order logic? I.e., can one introduce similar notions when the language is not first-order, and so "classify" kinds of objects which are intrinsically higher-order?

Sorry if the question is vague (hope it has at least sense), but before going through I would just like to satisfy this curiosity.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, you will have to move from geometric to logical morphisms. Look at the Ph.D [thesis](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/thesis/thesis.ps.gz) of Awodey.

PS. That chapter is amazing.